# how to delete UITableView Cell after document gets removed from Firestore console

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

since of starting my project now i didn't find any answer about how to delete the UITableView cell from an outside source,  I'm struggling here about how to delete UITableview Rows or Cells after it gets deleted from My FireStore Cloud Storage, I want to remove the value from the array and delete that cell without using `canEditRowAt indexPath` cause I want to delete it in
one more thing I don't know how to use dictionaries with arrays, and I don't know if I have to use it in such a case

```
struct accepteddriverData {

var driverName: String
var userPhone: String
var username: String
var driverPhone: String

}


func driverSelected(arg: Bool, completion: (Bool) -> ()){
guard let driverid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
        let firestore = Firestore.firestore()
        let doc = firestore.collection("offers").whereField("driverUid", isEqualTo: driverid).whereField("selected", isEqualTo: true)
        doc.addSnapshotListener { (querysnap, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            }
            querysnap?.documentChanges.forEach({ (change) in
                
                self.DriverData = []

                if (change.type == .added) {
                    
                    
                let snap = change.document.data()

                let driverName = snap["driverName"] as? String ?? ""
                let userPhone = snap["userPhone"] as? String ?? ""
                let username = snap["userName"] as? String ?? ""
                let driverPhone = snap["driverPhone"] as? String ?? ""

               let accepted = accepteddriverData(driverName: driverName, userPhone: userPhone, username: username, driverPhone: driverPhone)

               self.DriverData.append(accepted)
                    
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.DriverOrdersTV.reloadData()
                            
                }
}
                if (change.type == .removed){ // i want to delete tableView cell on this statement
                    let id = change.document.documentID
                    let snap = change.document.data()
                    print(id)
                    print(snap)
                    
                }
                    
            })
}
completion(arg)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your model

```
var docId: String
```

then inside

```
if (change.type == .removed){  
   let id = change.document.documentID
   self.DriverData.removeAll(where:{ $0.docId == id })
   // refresh table
 }
```

Comment: why `var docId: int` is an integer while the Firestore documentId is a `String` + when calling `removeAll` all the my tableview cells get deleted

Comment: which value do i have to assign to `var docId: int`

Comment: Assign `change.document.documentID`

Comment: is there any other solution or do I have to just work with that cause its still deleting all my cells even the ones with the different id's after calling `tableView.reloadData()`